How to add metadata (name, symbles, ...) to spl token?
I am using @solana/spl-token to create spl token, but I cant add metadata to the token, I know TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID can do that, but how can I make it works with TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID?
Here is my code:
transaction.add(addPriorityFee);
  transaction.add(
      SystemProgram.createAccount({
        fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
        newAccountPubkey: keypair.publicKey,
        space: MINT_SIZE,
        lamports,
        programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      }),
      createInitializeMint2Instruction(keypair.publicKey, decimals, mintAuthority, freezeAuthority, programId)
  );
  const signature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(CONNECTION, transaction, [payer, keypair], confirmOptions);


You will need to add that using Metaplex Metadata Program](https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata)
Using UMI and the helpers that they provide, you can have both create SPL and add metadata instructions in a single method that they provide which you can use like this
import { createUmi } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults";
import { percentAmount, generateSigner, some } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi'
import { createFungible } from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata'

const umi = createUmi(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));

const mint = generateSigner(umi)
await createFungible(umi, {
  mint,
  name: 'My Fungible',
  uri: 'https://example.com/my-fungible.json',
  sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(5.5),
  decimals: some(7), // for 0 decimals use some(0)
}).sendAndConfirm(umi)

Don't forget to update with your NFT metadata for the name, symbol and off chain URI.
I wouldn't recommend using the old JS SDK because it isn't actively maintained.
